# Установил vpn и перестал работать nginx+phpfpm

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, vpn

Все работало красиво, nginx+phpfpm!
Черт дернул установить vpn. Нужен статический ip для работы.
Установил вот это PoPTop  pptpd
Делал по этому руководству http://www.comss.ru/page.php?id=2512
Ну и сразу вывалились все сайты в 500 ошибку
хотя nginx пашет
в логе сайта

```
2016/08/23 00:19:43 [error] 8920#8920: *64 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 69.162.124.237, server: xxx.ru, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9001", host: "xxxxxx.ru", referrer: "http://xxxxxxx.ru/"
```

Comment: вероятно, *phpfpm* не слушает 9001-й порт на адресе 127.0.0.1. и с работой программы *pptpd* это вряд ли связано.

Comment: ну все работало. phpfpm перезапускал уже
в netstat все есть... мистика

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ был в вопросе.
При установке pptpd внес правило в таблицу

```
echo "Обновление IPtables Routing и добавление этого в автозагрузку"
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to $ip
# saves iptables routing rules and enables them on-boot
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.conf
```

я его удалил, перезагрузил весь сервер
и заработало (не понял как перезагрузить службу, не работало не хотела перезапускаться)